# How to check date format in Excel

Tags: excel, datetime

I have around 20,000 records in an Excel file and around four columns which have dates. I am trying to insert those into SQL. However date columns have dates in incorrect format eg; `02/092015` or `02/90/2015` or `2015`. So checking 20,000 records one by one would be very lengthy.

I tried to count `/` but it didn't work. It changes the format of column to date.

I was looking for some formula which can check the format and maybe color the cell or something like it.

Comment: How about using autofilter? You should be able to tell quite quickly from there what needs changing.

Comment: I'd follow Dave's suggestion and just correct those. You'll just have to find quick fixes for similar problems. Example: `02/092015`, you can quickly solve this by replacing `2015` with `/2015`.

Answer (score 3):

I was running across this issue today, and would like to add on to what nekomatic started.

Before we begin, the `TEXT` formula needs to follow the date format we are working with.  If your dates are in month/day/year format, then your second argument for the `TEXT` formula would be "mm/dd/yyyy".  If it is in the format day/month/year, then the formula would need to use "dd/mm/yyyy".  For the purposes of my answer here, I am going to have my dates in month/day/year format.

Now, let's assume that cell A1 contains the value `12/1/2015`, cell A2 contains the value `monkey`, and cell A3 contains the value `2015`.  Further, let's assume our minimum acceptable date is December 1st, 2000.

In column B, we will enter the formula

`=IF(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"mm/dd/yyyy"))),"not a date",IF(A1 >=DATEVALUE(TEXT("01/01/2000","mm/dd/yyyy")),A1,"not a valid date"))`

The above formula will validate correct dates, test against non-date values, incomplete dates, and date values outside of an acceptable minimal value.

Our results in column B should then show `12/1/2015`, `not a date`, and `not a valid date`.

Answer (score 0):

Two of the examples you give are text which may be identified with Conditional Formatting by applying a formula rule such as:

```
=ISTEXT(A1)
```

and colouring the result as you wish.  There would be an issue if *all* your dates (even those of valid format) are also text but I'm guessing that is not the case.

For the third example (ie `2015`) a CF formula rule such as:

```
=AND(A1<2500,A1>0)
```

may help.

If your columns are a mixture of what should be dates and other entries that are properly text strings your approach may be better than the more general `ISTEXT`, for example a CF formula rule of:

```
=FIND("/",A1)>0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a column to the Excel sheet with the formula

```
=DATEVALUE(TEXT(A1,"dd/mm/yyyy"))
```

this should return `#VALUE` if the contents of A1 are not a valid date in dd/mm/yyyy format. You can filter on this value to identify the incorrect records.

Edit: If A1 contains only `2015` this formula returns `07/07/1905` (if the formula cell is formatted as date) so you can spot these by filtering for dates before the earliest correct date your file should contain.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a correct date that fails? It works OK when I try it. You could try breaking out the `TEXT` function in a separate cell to check what that's returning.

Comment: date that showed #VALUE is 13/10/1970, 10/02/1977 few example, however I have formatted them as date and English UK.