# Clear all cells which do not have a valid date

Tags: excel, vba

I have entries in column A starting from A2. Some cells contain dates, some are blanks, some cells contains text and numbers.

I want to clear cells which do not contain a valid date.

Comment: you can adopt this method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28428061/how-to-check-date-format-in-excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA has an IsDate function that is pretty reliable in determining whether a cell's content is a legitimate date or not.

```
sub scrubNonDates()

    dim i as long

    with worksheets("sheet1")
        for i=2 to .cells(.rows.count, "A").end(xlup).row
            if not ISDATE(.cells(i, "A")) then .cells(i, "A").clear
        next i
    end with

end sub
```

Comment: date  
01/04/2018  
05/04/2018  
  
07/04/2018  

08/04/2018  

i have above data in a workbook name "ravi" and sheet name "sheet1" and data start from "A1" TILL "A4", ABOVE CODE IS NOT WORKING.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i was making mistake , its working properly. Thanks a Lot Dear.